# Positioning images within SVG

Tags: svg

I'm trying to get images to position within each hexagon on an SVG, these will eventually be dynamic.

I'm finding that the images and both zoomed and not central - I have tried using X/Y attributes to counter this, but it's still not right.

How can each image be centred in each hexagon?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 820.77 566.4">
 <defs>
     <style>
     .four-hexagon-svg-1,.four-hexagon-svg-2,.four-hexagon-svg-3,.four-hexagon-svg-4{
         stroke:#ff5400;
         stroke-width:5px;
     }
     .four-hexagon-svg-1{
         fill:url(#four-image-1);
     }
     .four-hexagon-svg-2{
         fill:url(#four-image-2);
     }
     .four-hexagon-svg-3{
         fill:url(#four-image-3);
     }
     .four-hexagon-svg-4{
         fill:url(#four-image-4);
     }
     </style>
     <pattern id="four-image-1" width="100%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/686/800/800" x="0" y="50" />
     </pattern>
     <pattern id="four-image-2" width="100%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/688/800/800" x="0" y="-50" />
     </pattern>
     <pattern id="four-image-3" width="100%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/450/800/800" x="45" y="0"  />
     </pattern>
     <pattern id="four-image-4" width="100%" height="100%" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
         <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/400/800/800" x="-45" y="0" />
     </pattern>
 </defs>
 <g>
     <g>
         <path class="four-hexagon-svg-1" d="M489.09,295.5h-155L256.65,429.7l77.48,134.2h155l77.48-134.2Z" />
         <g>
             <g>
                 <path class="four-hexagon-svg-2" d="M489.09,2.5h-155L256.65,136.7l77.48,134.2h155l77.48-134.2Z" />
             </g>
         </g>
         <g>
             <g>
                 <path class="four-hexagon-svg-3" d="M740.41,148.38h-155L508,282.58l77.48,134.2h155l77.48-134.2Z" />
             </g>
         </g>
         <g>
             <g>
                 <path class="four-hexagon-svg-4" d="M235.33,148.38h-155L2.89,282.58l77.48,134.2h155l77.48-134.2Z" />
             </g>
         </g>
     </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using patterns I'm using clipPath to cut the image with the hexagon. Also I'm using only one hexagon path with the center in the origin of the svg canvas (0,0). The images are also with the center in the origin of the svg canvas: `<image width="310" height="310" x="-155" y="-155"...` (I see that your images are squares)
For the red border I'm reusing the hexagon: `<use xlink:href="#hex" />`
I'm putting both the image and the use element in a group and I'm translating the group where you need it.

I hope this is what you need

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 820.77 566.4">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp">    
<path id="hex" d="M77.5,-134.2h-155l-77.44,134.2l77.48,134.2h155l77.48,-134.2z"  />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
 <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
          use{fill:none; stroke:#ff5400; stroke-width:5}
         ]]> 
  </style>
        <g transform="translate(411.59,429.7)">
            <image width="310" height="310" x="-155" y="-155" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/686/800/800" clip-path="url(#cp)"  />
            <use xlink:href="#hex" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(411.59,136.7)">
            <image width="310" height="310" x="-155" y="-155"  xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/688/800/800" x="0" y="-50" clip-path="url(#cp)" />
            <use xlink:href="#hex" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(662.91,282.58)">
            <image width="310" height="310" x="-155" y="-155" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/450/800/800" x="45" y="0" clip-path="url(#cp)"  />
          <use xlink:href="#hex" />
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(157.83,282.58)">
          <image width="310" height="310" x="-155" y="-155" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/400/800/800" x="-45" y="0" clip-path="url(#cp)"  />
          <use xlink:href="#hex" />
        </g> 
</svg>
```

Observation: I'm using your hexagon path, although it's not mathematically perfect.